# How do I regex split with variable values?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string:

> 21>Please be specific. What do you mean by that?21>Hello are you there623>Simon?

I want to split it into:

```
21>Please be specific. What do you mean by that?
21>Hello are you there
623>Simon?
```

Basically the splitter is the numeric value (21 and 623 in this case) followed by the `>`.

My implementation is that I find the `>` char, then walk back until I find a non-numeric value.

So basically using `sub-string` and the like.  But it's ugly and I am certain there is a better Regex implementation, but I don't know enough about it.

So can Regex be used here?

Comment: Maybe something like `\d{1,3}>`?  Or maybe even `\d+>`?  First one would look for 1 to 3 digits followed by `>`, and the second would look for one or more digits followed by `>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with look ahead and look behind, so that your match is the zero length area between what you want to split.

```
string s = "21>Please be specific. What do you mean by that?21>Hello are you there623>Simon?";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<=\D)(?=\d+>)");
var r = reg.Split(s);
foreach(var i in r)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Will output

> 21>Please be specific. What do you mean by that?
>
> 21>Hello are you there
>
> 623>Simon?

Comment: @noob Yep, and I think our answers complement each other.

Answer (score 3):

Try with following regex. It matches the zero width between `something` and `number>`

**Regex:** `(?<=\D)(?=\d+>)` replaced with `\n` for demo.

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\D)` looks behind to see if it's not a number.
- `(?=\d+>)` looks ahead to see if it's a `number>`.

And matched the `zer0-width` between them.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK5wZ4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try: `[0-9]+>`

## Explanation:

- `[0-9]+` At least 1 digit
- `>` followed by `>`

---

It might make sense to replace the matches with `\n$0`, which will move them to individual lines.

Comment: Wouldn't `\d+>` be equivalent?

Comment: If you use that with `Regex.Split` it's going to remove the matches.  I think the OP's asking how to keep the matches.

Comment: @Tim `\d` includes any unicode digit, and will be slower. It's better to use `[0-9]` unless you need to find Persian digits or something.